# Python itertools product, but conditional?

Tags: python, python-2.7, product, python-itertools

I have a function fun that takes several parameters p0,p1,.. For each parameter i give a list of possible values:

```
p0_list = ['a','b','c']
p1_list = [5,100]
```

I can now call my function for every combination of p0,p1

```
for i in itertools.product(*[p0,p1]):
    print fun(i)
```

Now comes the problem: What if i already know, that the parameter p1 only has an effect on the result of fun, if p0 is 'a' or 'c'? In this case i need my list of parameter combinations to look like:

```
[('a', 5), ('a',100), ('b', 5), ('c',5), ('c', 100)]
```

So ('b', 100) is just omitted, as it would be an unecessary evaluation of fun.

**My final Solution**:

```
param_lists = [['p0', ['a','b','c']],['p1', [5,100]]]
l = itertools.product(*[x[1] for x in param_lists])
l = [x for x in l if not x[0] == 'b' or x[1]==5]
```

I used this approach for 5 parameters and various conditions and it works fine. It's pretty easy to read as well. This code is inspired by Corley Brigmans' and nmcleans' answers.

Comment: I would personally just memoize your function calls and call it with every combination.

Comment: That would require a method to tell which combinations give the same results, which would then give me the opportunity to delete those combinations. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate it, and then suppress 'duplicates'. But probably just better to generate separately:

```
p0_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
p0_noarg1 = ['b']
sp0_noarg1 = set(p0_noarg1)
p0_arg1 = [x for x in p0_list if x not in sp0_noarg1]
p1_list = [5, 100]

total_list = [x for x in itertools.product(p0_arg1, p1_list)] + [x for x in itertools.product(p0_noarg1, p1_list[:1])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! But of course the solution is nasty when dealing with 2+ parameters. However i do not think i can expect a more elegant solution as the problem is so nasty.

Comment: Can you tell me why you use set() here ? I tried it and it also works without set().

Comment: Looking up an item in a `set` (aka hashtable) is an O(1) operation - it's more or less fixed time - you calculate the index where it should be, look there, and it's either there or it's not (ignoring hash collisions, which should be rare). Looking up an item in a `list` is an O(n) operation - you have to look at every item every time to determine that the item is not there. It does take a small amount of time to generate the set in the first place, but it's almost always worth it.

Comment: btw, no reason why it couldn't be extended to multiple parameters - if you need me to write it out, i can try, but as a hint: `product(a,b,c)` == `product(*[a,b,c])`...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman This creates a new set on each iteration, though. To get the speed benefit you'll need to move the `set` call out of the list comprehension.

Comment: you are right... usually, that's in my code anyways, for this example i was lazy :) i can never remember when python binds that in the list comprehension. it is in fact way faster to do the set ahead of time, so i edited this to match.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general filter function that could work for this:

```
def without_duplicate_item(groups, index, item):
    seen = False
    for group in groups:
        if group[index] == item:
            if seen:
                continue
            seen = True
        yield group
```

Usage:

```
param_groups = itertools.product(*[p0_list, p1_list])

param_groups = without_duplicate_item(param_groups, 0, "b")
```

You can of course keep adding filters for different parameters. This should be quite memory-efficient, compared to storing previous calls, because it essentially only stores one boolean value `seen` per filter.