# Combinatoric in Python Lists

Tags: python

I have (say 2) Lists and I want to get all combinations between the elements in thoose lists BUT I want to put conditions in. So for example if the Element in the first List is `"yes"` , the Elements of the Second should be considered if they are "ifyes" in creating the combination and if the Element is "No" than not.

I already know how to get all kind of combinations between a List of Lists ( I used the itertools lib ) :

```
import itertools

list_d = [["yes","no"],["ifyes","ifyes2","ifno"]]

#in this way we can use a for loop to iterate through the combinations
iterator_d=itertools.product(*list_d)
```

So the Output I wish for but dont get should be something like :

```
["yes","ifyes"] ,["yes","ifyes2"],["no","ifno"]
```

Comment: Can you filter once you generate all "unfiltered" possible conditions, or do you need to filter at generation time?

Comment: This is a really vague definition why the output is `["yes","ifyes"] ,["yes","ifyes2"],["no","ifno"]`?

Comment: @GPhilo a filter at Generation time would be very helpful , but if that is not possible I have to do it the other way ( after I got the unfiltered results)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the question here.  How does one get the output from the description? And the sample doesn't match the description either...

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thats the Output I wish.... not the actual Output of the function above

Comment: The output that you wish does not seems to match the description

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464743/python-itertools-product-but-conditional) is a good starting point

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but your question mentions 5 lists, so what happens to lists 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: @Deepstop I hope everything makes sense now

Comment: How does this scale up? You originally said you have 5 lists, if the data is `[["yes", "no"], ["ifyes", "ifyes2", "ifno"], ['anotheryes'], [None, 'justyes', 'justno', 'justno2'], ['N/A', None]]`, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list comprehension that will give you the desired output for the two lists.

```
import itertools

list_d = [["yes","no"],["ifyes","ifyes2","ifno"]]

#in this way we can use a for loop to iterate through the combinations
iterator_d=itertools.product(*list_d)

x = [[i,j] for i,j in iterator_d if i in j]
```

```
Result:
x = [['yes', 'ifyes'], ['yes', 'ifyes2'], ['no', 'ifno']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet which gives you required output in case if you have list of 2 lists,

```
def myList(inp):
    out = []
    iter, comp = inp
    for i in iter:
        out.extend([[i, l] for l in comp if i in l])
    return out


val = [["yes","no"],["ifyes","ifyes2","ifno"]]
print("output is = ", myList(val))
output is = [['yes', 'ifyes'], ['yes', 'ifyes2'], ['no', 'ifno']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-iterator method which doesn't depend on the property that the text of the elements in the first list is contained in an element of the second.

```
mapper = {'ifyes': 'yes', 'ifyes2': 'yes', 'ifno': 'no'}
list_d = [["yes","no"],["ifyes","ifyes2","ifno"]]

print([[mapper[j], j] for j in list_d[1] for i in list_d[0] if mapper[j] == i])
```

Result

```
[['yes', 'ifyes'], ['yes', 'ifyes2'], ['no', 'ifno']]
```